# CentOS vhosts causing issues with Vagrant Share command

Tags: centos, vagrant

I'm running Vagrant on my Mac. I have a CentOS 6.4 box running with the  Virtualbox provider and puppet (not important in this context). This is a basic Vagrantfile to show the issue I have:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # centos box information
    config.vm.box = "nrel/CentOS-6.5-x86_64"

    config.vm.hostname = "devbox.loc"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.187"
    config.vm.network "public_network"

end
```

I've got a few vhosts setup which i'm accessing on urls like devsite.loc and othersite.loc by modifying the hosts file on my Mac with the private network IP. This all works as expected and I can access each of these vhosts via their addresses, seeing the correct site.

Basic vhost file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/devsite/public_html
        ServerName devsite.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/othersite/public_html
        ServerName othersite.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

However, if I try to run `vagrant share` it fails with this error:

> ```
> default: Local machine address: 192.168.10.187
> ```
>
> /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)

If I remove the vhosts file then vagrant share works, sharing the default Apache page. Something about `vagrant share` clearly dislikes something about my vhosts file but I have no idea what it might be.

FWIW I'm using the latest versions of Vagrant and Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue here was actually the site within the vhost. It contained a `.htaccess` which added a `www.` prefix to URLs with a number of domain name exceptions (including any domain name ending in .loc). The fact that `vagrant share` attempted to connect via http using the IP address rather than a domain name, this rule was triggered and it seems the redirection to `www.192.168.10.187` caused the ruby error as this was an inaccessible URL. In short - my bad.

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same issue. This solution solved it for me.